# How to redirect ls to the cd command

Tags: bash, ls

I want to do `ls | grep something` and `cd` to the one thing that is listed. I tried with `|` and searched, but nothing found. Is it using `xargs`?

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: You don't provide any kind of example or input; please tell us what exactly you wish to achieve.

Comment: `xargs` won't work, as it is a separate process, but the current working directory is specific to each process. So you have to use a shell builtin command, not some binary you start as a separate process.

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
$ cd $( ls | grep foo )
```

but that will only work if the result is relative to where you are currently; for anything more you'll want `find` (it will print paths) and a very specific `grep` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern you want to match can be expressed as a glob, and you know that there will only be one match, you can let your shell do the matching:

```
$ cd *foo*
```

Otherwise the easiest option is to command substitution to provide the parameter to `cd`:

```
$ cd $(ls | grep '*foo*' | head -n1)
```